# Passing model data to nvd3 chart in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, charts

I'm trying to replace default chart data with real data in the form of a Model element of type string .  Can anyone please demonstrate the correct syntax to accomplish this?  Many thanks in advance.

The script function for .datum that displays using the default data:

```
function cumulativeTestData() {
    return [
        {
            key: "Closing Prices",
            mean: 60,
            values: [[1083297600000, 0.77078283705125], [1085976000000, 1.8356366650335], [1088568000000, 5.3121322073127], [1091246400000, 4.9320975829662], [1093924800000, 3.9835408823225], [1096516800000, 6.8694685316805], [1099195200000, 8.4854877428545], [1101790800000, 15.933627197384], [1104469200000, 15.920980069544], [1107147600000, 12.478685045651]]
        },
    ];
}
```

Samples of what I've tried:

```
values: @Model.ClosesJson //didn't work

values: <text> @Model.ClosesJson </text> //didn't work

values: $("#ClosesJson").val() //Model entity as hidden - didn't work
```

Controller and Model string entity to clone the default data Unix syntax:

```
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
    ProjectEntities projectDb = new ProjectEntities();

    var model = new DashboardViewModel();
    model.Closes = new List<ClosesModel>();
    var prices = projectDb.uspGetCloses().ToList();
    foreach (var result in prices)
    {
        var close = new ClosesModel
        {
            Close = result.Close,
            CloseCreatedDate = result.CloseCreatedDate
        };
        model.Closes.Add(close);
    }

    model.ClosesJson = "[[" + System.Convert.ToString(model.Closes[0]. CloseCreatedDate.Subtract(new DateTime(1970,1,1)).TotalMilliseconds) + ", " + 
            System.Convert.ToString(model.Closes[0]. Close) + "]";
    for (int i = 1; i < model.Closes.Count; i ++)
    {
        model.ClosesJson = model.ClosesJson + ", [" + System.Convert.ToString(model.Closes[i].CloseCreatedDate.Subtract(new DateTime(1970,1,1)).TotalMilliseconds) +
                ", " + System.Convert.ToString(model.Closes[i].Close) + "]";
    }
    model.ClosesJson = model.ClosesJson + "]";

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently just passing a string, not an object that can be represented as JSON.

Because you need to pass an array containing an array of 2 values (representing the charts x and y values, you will need to create an anonymous object

and in your main model, add a property

```
public object Coordinates { get; set; }
```

Then in the controller

```
model.Coordinates = new[]
{
    new []{1083297600000, 0.77078283705125F},
    new []{1085976000000, 1.8356366650335F}
};
```

And then in your script

```
var values = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Coordinates))');
```

To construct the required array format from your model, you can use

```
DateTime baseDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
object[] array = new object[prices.Count];
for(int i = 0; i < prices.Count; i++)
{
  array[i] = new[]
  {
    prices[i].CloseCreatedDate.Subtract(baseDate).TotalMilliseconds, 
    prices[i].Close
  };
}
model.Coordinates = array;
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  The code is trying to pull prices and dates associated with those prices and make a string enclosed in brackets with each [date, price] also in brackets to clone the default data's apparent syntax.  The date value was in Unix, so that's what the last bit of Controller code did.  Using your suggestions, the chart shows a line with no slope and the dates all read 12/31/69 (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226438/javascript-date-object-returning-december-31st-1969), but the html source shows the "var values" as seemingly correct.  Any ideas?

Comment: That's an issue associated with the plugin your using and/or the format of the data your passing to it. My answer was only addressing how to pass the data correctly in the format you indicated. Does it work correctly when you hard code the values as per your first snippet? But from the linked answer it appears that the format should actually be `[{x: 1083297600000, y: 0.77078283705125 }, {x: ..., y: ...}]` anyway - in which case I will need to adjust my answer (and this format would make it easier anyway)

Comment: Yes, the default data in the original seems to work fine.  The html for the values is "var closes =  JSON.parse('[{"Close":4.152,"CloseCreatedDate":"\/Date(1367359200000)\/"}, etc.".  That looks correct, but am I missing something?  The chart shows a vertical line on the y-axis with no slope and the dates all read "12/31/69" as if the chart can't read the date.

Comment: No that definitely looks wrong. Can you confirm if the hard coded values in the first snippet are working.

Comment: Yes, the hard coded values in the first snippet are charted correctly.

Comment: Can you also confirm if the following hard code values also work `values: [{ x: 1083297600000, y: 0.77078283705125 }, { x: 1085976000000, y: 1.8356366650335 }]`

Comment: Those couple of hard coded values in "x:, y:" format do not seem to be working.  The chart looks like the previous comment where the line is vertical on the y-axis with no slope, and the 3 date values across the x-axis read "12/31/69".

Comment: OK, it could then be an issue with the actual format of the first value because I am passing a `float` when it may expect a `int` for the x value. When you hard code the values in the controller (see my 3rd code block), can you confirm what `var values = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Coordinates))');` actually returns - i.e what is the value of `console.log(values);`

Comment: Dammit, I also had a error in my 3rd block of code anyway - see update before you test it.

Comment: Well, I haven't hard coded that exact model in the 3rd code block, but the ClosesModel in the view model's List<ClosesModel> just contains a decimal Close and DateTime CloseDate.  The 1st database values are 4.152 and 2013-04-30 17:00:00:000, and the html seemed to be showing with "var closes = JSON.parse('[{"Close":4.152,"CloseCreatedDate":"\/Date(1367359200000)\/"},".  Does that help?

Comment: That is definitely wrong. But having had a look at a few other Q/A relating to the plugin, I think I know how to solve this (and it will involve creating an anonymous object collection). Give me 15 minutes to test it and I will let you know

Comment: Have updated answer. Can you try this out (i.e. just using hard coded values to see if it works), then I can look at how to generate this from your property values.

Comment: This certainly looks promising.  The x-axis date values range from 2004-04-29 to 2004-05-30, and the html shows "var closes = JSON.parse('[[1.08329763E+12,0.7707828],[1.085976E+12,1.83563662]]')".

Comment: OK, Give me another 15 minutes and I'll update the answer to show how to construct it based on your model (its a bit messy, but necessary because your plugin wont accept objects (only arrays which is a bit limiting) although there may be a cleaner way (just can't think of it yet)

Comment: Getting the "no best type found for implicitly-typed array" error on the line "array[i] = new[]".  I tried making it "array[i] = new object[]", but then got an out of range exception.  Still working through it.

Comment: Have you changed the model property to `public object Coordinates { get; set; }` (it need to be `object`). Its working fine for me with `array[i] = new[]{ 100, 0.111 };` i.e. hard coding the values so maybe there is some issue with your model types?

Comment: OK, It should have been `new object[prices.Count]` see update

Comment: It was the line "object[] array = new object[prices.Count - 1];" in that last code block.  Changing it to "object[] array = new object[prices.Count];" fixed the out of range exception.  The y-values are incorrect on the chart, but correct in the JSON.parse.  I'll try tracking that down, but any suggestions would be very welcomed.  The dates and x-values of each point look correct, though!  Stephen, you are a life-saver.  I can't give enough upvotes.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the nvd3 chart so can't really help with that. You can always ask a new question :) (and best if you include the `nvd3.js` tag)